# Referenced dll (built from referenced projects) are locked after each build in Xamarin Forms Portable project?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, dll, build, xamarin.forms

I'm building my first Xamarin Forms app (I've built one before but it's a Xamarin Android app). There is one weird issue that will prevent me from debugging my app each time. The main Xamarin Forms Portable project has 2 other references from other portable library projects. So after each build on the Android project (just an example), the 2 output DLLs (from the referenced projects) are locked (by ***devenv.exe***). That means I cannot simply rebuild it while keeping VS open. I have to close the VS and delete the output DLLs manually before re-opening my projects and build again. That's completely not acceptable.

I've found out that somehow the output dlls are cached in a folder named ***ProjectAssemblies*** and it's usually located at *C:\Users[UserAccount]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ProjectAssemblies* (for Visual Studio 2015).

BUT that's just a strange signal I've recognized, I mean it seems not be the actual problem because even when I deleted all the files there, after restarting VS the output dlls are somehow still loaded into ***devenv.exe*** (I used Process Hacker to find those dlls and know that they are loaded by ***devenv.exe***). The only way to prevent that is to delete the output dlls in the folder ***bin***. But that works just once, if rebuilding the projects I have to redo all those steps (closing VS, deleting output dlls, reopening VS).

The only final way may be to just add the output DLLs as reference (not the projects) but that would not allow to debug code in the referenced projects easily (still the referenced projects are part of the main solution, they are not some kind of ready-to-use separate libraries).

### Update

By using Process Hacker, I know that some essential DLLs for Xamarin Forms project (such as Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll) are also loaded into ***devenv.exe*** BUT they are loaded from the path in ***ProjectAssemblies*** (as mentioned before). So those DLLs are not locked, they can be cleaned OK from the ***bin*** folder. But somehow my project dlls are not treated that same way. There seem to be 2 versions loaded into ***devenv.exe***, one from the ***ProjectAssemblies*** and the other is from the ***bin*** folder (of platform-specific projects, not of the main portable project). So that's why it's locked and cannot be cleaned/overwritten while rebuilding.

Comment: I had a similar problem with VS2017 and Xamarin.Forms project. I fixed it by deleting all of the bin and obj folders in all of the referenced projects and the main app project. Shut down VS, in windows explorer or command prompt go through all of the referenced projects, delete their bin and obj folders. After restarting VS and doing a complete rebuild, my builds have worked ever since. This was on VS2017, so it's a little different, so not sure if VS2015 can be worked around in the same way.

Comment: @PedroSilva thank you for your input. Well actually I found out that the problem raises only after a build is failed (such as for some syntax error). So once that happens, I need to close VS, delete the dlls in bin folder and reopen VS. But if I carefully avoid syntax errors before building and debugging, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are hitting this [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/54945/compilaion-fails-because-proces-cannot-access-dll.html) (Compilaion fails because proces cannot access dll) that was fixed in version 15.2 (26430.12). Check out the [release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes)

That particular bug was a nightmare for many devs, me included.

If that´s the case, updating VisualStudio will fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is my case (see my comment to Predro Silva on my question), but still thank you for the answer. Currently I will avoid updating VS (the current version I have is 14.0 (23107.0) because of huge time consuming it may do. I'll give this answer 1 upvote but still not sure if accepting is fine.